# Passing a reference to the jQuery object which invoked a jQuery plugin method (window object)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass `$(window)` as an argument to some function, but when I try to to get `scrollTop()` from inside the function it returns 0 but if I try to get `$(window).scrollTop` it gives me correct result.

Could you please tell me what is the mistake I am making, And If passing element as an argument is not the correct way then what could be its alternate.

Following is my code.

```
//Funtion Declaration
$.fn.someFunction = function (element) {
        var container = $(this),
        viewTop = element.scrollTop(),
        console.log($(window).scrollTop());//returns correct value
        console.log(viewTop);//returns 0
}


//Calling the function
$fn.otherFunction = function(){
         $(el).someFunction($(this));
}

$(window).otherFunction();
```

And same is the case with height of the window.

```
// Following is the actual Code. It may be messy to look at but still.

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(window).scrolling();
    $(".footer").displayFooter();
});

$.fn.scrolling = function () {
    $(".parallax_active").each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).parallax($(this));
    })
// some more stuff goes here.
};


$.fn.parallax = function (parent) {
    var container = $(this),
            viewTop = parent.scrollTop(),
            viewHeight = parent.height(),
            viewHeader = $(".header-container").outerHeight(),
            viewBottom = viewTop + viewHeight,
            header = viewTop + viewHeader;
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    console.log(viewTop);
    console.log(viewHeight);
}
```

Thanks,
Arpita

Comment: So sounds like `this` isn't referring to `window` object. You need to provide more context regarding how you call this function. BTW, i don't see why don't you just use the `window` object

Comment: if you have jquery function, the parameter is not needed in this case because this mean $(el). You can access inside function via this.

Comment: it is actually $(el).someFunction($(this)); is being called from within some other function like $(window).otherFunction();

Comment: @Arpita Just check it, `this` isn't referring to window as i can guess it. Anyway, you have to provide relevant code in question itself

Comment: You would have to do: $(el).someFunction.apply(window, [this]); I think

Comment: Updated my code snippet please review.

Comment: @Arpita Why can't you do `$(el).someFunction($(window))`?

Comment: This isn't really code you are using, because posted one contains some typos So please provide relevant code and sample to replicate issue

Comment: @vihan because otherFunction is not going to be called always from $(window) only some times it would be called by $(".someClass").otherFunction as well.

Comment: FYI, inside `$.fn.method`, `this` is already a jq object

Comment: @ A. Wolff Surely I'll update the code snippet.

Comment: added the actual code.

Comment: so ya, inside `each` loop, `this` isn't referring to `window`

Comment: You caught me. Thanks J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `.each()` method, `this` refers to the element you are iterating over.

If you want `this` to be bound to the element that called the `.scrolling()` method, get a reference to `this` *outside* of the `.each()` method:

```
$.fn.scrolling = function () {
    var self = this;
    $(".parallax_active").each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).parallax($(self));
    })
};
```

You could also clearly pass a jQuery object that contains the `window` object too:

```
$(el).parallax($(window));
```